# ios swift how to interact with outlets in custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

nomrally i have one view controller and i add outlets to it. and inside view did load i can change the font of the text view or i can add images to the ui image. but now i have a custom cell like this:

```
class NumberOfPeopleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfPeopleLabel: UILabel!
```

as you see, i have outlet in that cell, how can i interact with that outlet? there is no view did load function inside the table view cell

Answer (score 2):

You could set the font of the label in your storyboard.

Or you could set the font of the label in `awakeFromNib` (a method you can override in your cell class).

Or you could set the font of the label in `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` (in your table view controller).

Comment: Hey Rob, I'm trying to do what you're suggesting, change things in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method via an outlet but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here's the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55315771/swift-cant-edit-properties-of-custom-table-cell-programatically

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, the "standard" approach would be, inside your `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("<Your Id Here>", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NumberOfPeopleTableViewCell
        let foo = cell.numberOfPeopleLabel // DO STUFF WITH IT
        // Do more stuff here
        return cell
}
```

OR --

If you want to keep your View Controller code clean of graphics layout-ing / appearance logic (which you should) consider, inside `NumberOfPeopleTableViewCell` to override `func layoutSubviews()`.

OR (my favourite) --

You could subclass the UITextView (e.g. `MYCellTextView`) and change the appearance for all of your subclass instances in your app delegate using UIApparence.  Like this should work:

```
MyCellTextView.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "<myFont>", size: 10.0)
```

You can put the above, for example, in your app delegate.  This has the advantage of keeping appearance code in one place and away from view controllers (and generic, for all instances of your custom view).

Answer (score 0):

You can **override** the function `layoutSubviews`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    //do whatever here for your outlets        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `awakeFromNib`. as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib) states:

**When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet instance variables set.**

so you can do:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()

  numberOfPeopleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0) // or whatever font you want to assign
}
```